# create median and average column out of array column in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following spark dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4], 'col': [[1,2,None, None], [1,1,2,2], [1,1,1,2], [1,None,None,None]]})

foo_dfs = spark.createDataFrame(foo)
foo_dfs.show()
```

```
+---+------------+
| id|         col|
+---+------------+
|  1|    [1, 2,,]|
|  2|[1, 1, 2, 2]|
|  3|[1, 1, 1, 2]|
|  4|      [1,,,]|
+---+------------+
```

I am creating the `min_col` and `max_col` by doing the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
foo_dfs = foo_dfs.withColumn('min_col', f.array_min('col'))
foo_dfs = foo_dfs.withColumn('max_col', f.array_max('col'))
```

which outputs:

```
+---+------------+-------+-------+
| id|         col|min_col|max_col|
+---+------------+-------+-------+
|  1|    [1, 2,,]|      1|      2|
|  2|[1, 1, 2, 2]|      1|      2|
|  3|[1, 1, 1, 2]|      1|      2|
|  4|      [1,,,]|      1|      1|
+---+------------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to also add the `mean_col` and `median_col` next to the `max_col`. How can I do that ? As far as I know there is no `f.array_mean` or `f.array_median` function

The output dataframe should look like:

```
+---+------------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
| id|         col|min_col|max_col|mean_col|median_col|
+---+------------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
|  1|    [1, 2,,]|      1|      2|     1.5|       1.5|
|  2|[1, 1, 2, 2]|      1|      2|     1.5|       1.5|
|  3|[1, 1, 1, 2]|      1|      2|    1.25|       1.0|
|  4|      [1,,,]|      1|      1|     1.0|       1.0|
+---+------------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
```

So the `mean_col` and `median_col` calculation should **ignore** the `None` values

I tried this:

```
 import numpy as np
 array_median = f.udf(lambda x: float(np.nanmedian(x)), FloatType())
 array_mean = f.udf(lambda x: float(np.nanmean(x)), FloatType())
 foo_dfs.withColumn('median_col', array_median('col'))
 foo_dfs.withColumn('mean_col', array_mean('col'))
```

But it didn't work, I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the
> inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
> the casting rule ''safe''

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aggregate` function for the `mean_col` and `when` along with `array_sort` to get the `median_col`. But first, you need to filter null values from the array using `filter` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

foo_dfs = (foo_dfs.withColumn('col', F.array_sort(F.expr('filter(col, x -> x is not null)')))
           .withColumn('size', F.size('col'))
           .withColumn('min_col', F.array_min('col'))
           .withColumn('max_col', F.array_max('col'))
           .withColumn('mean_col', F.expr('aggregate(col, 0L, (acc,x) -> acc+x, acc -> acc /size)'))
           .withColumn('median_col', F.when(F.col('size') % 2 == 0,
                                            (F.expr('col[int(size/2)]') + F.expr('col[int(size/2)-1]'))/2
                                            ).otherwise(F.expr('col[int(size/2)]'))
                       )
           ).drop("size")

foo_dfs.show()
#+---+------------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
#| id|         col|min_col|max_col|mean_col|median_col|
#+---+------------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
#|  1|      [1, 2]|      1|      2|     1.5|       1.5|
#|  2|[1, 1, 2, 2]|      1|      2|     1.5|       1.5|
#|  3|[1, 1, 1, 2]|      1|      2|    1.25|       1.0|
#|  4|         [1]|      1|      1|     1.0|       1.0|
#+---+------------+-------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Some explanations:

- `mean_col`:  aggregate functions sums all the elements of the array then apply a finish lambda function which divides the resulting sum by the size of the array.
- `median_col`: sort the array and check its size: if `size%2 = 0` then addition the elements at indexes `size/2` and `size/2 -1` and divide by 2. Otherwise (`size%2 != 0`) the median correspond to element of index `size/2`.

Comment: what does the 0L in the aggregate mean ?

Comment: @quant it means type of initial value for `aggregate` function is long. `0D` for double for example. It should be the same type as the result of first lambda function `(acc, x) -> acc +x` otherwise spark throws mismatch exception. (in this case because your initial df has type `col: array<long>`)

Comment: I want to filter the 'None' in my array and so when I replace 'null' in the above code with 'None', I get a syntax error. Is there a special way to remove/ignore the None values?